# What does it mean when a merge replication generation has no changes?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication, merge-replication

According to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151789(v=sql.105).aspx),

> **MSmerge_genhistory** contains one row for each generation. A generation is a collection of changes that is delivered to a Publisher or Subscriber. Generations are closed each time the Merge Agent runs; subsequent changes in a database are added to one or more open generations.

Reading the above, it seems logical that all generations should have a number of changes. However, when I try to select rows from `MSmerge_genhistory`, I find a lot of them where the `changecount` column has a value of 0.

Do these rows indicate a problem? Why do generations exist if no changes are included in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generation with 0 changes is not indication of a problem. It is just indication that the generation contains no changes.

If you look at the statement you quoted from BOL, it reads "*Generations are closed each time the Merge Agent runs*", so this means that the Merge Agent could run and close the generations with no changes if no changes were performed on the publisher and/or subscribers.